# How to do column vector concatenation

Tags: list-manipulation, vector

Is it a way to do column vector concatenation?

```
u = {{1},{-1},{0}};
v = {{0},{1},{-1}};
w = {{-1},{0},{1}};
```

I would like a matrix of {u,v,w}

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given (for clarity),

```
u = {{a}, {b}, {c}};
v = {{d}, {e}, {f}};
w = {{g}, {h}, {i}};
```

I think you want,

```
expected1 = {{a, d, g}, {b, e, h}, {c, f, i}}
```

but maybe you want,

```
expected2 = {{a, b, c}, {d, e, f}, {g, h, i}}
```

In the first case:

```
Join[u, v, w, 2] == expected1
ArrayFlatten[{{u, v, w}}] == expected1
Flatten[{u, v, w}, {2, 3}] == expected1
```

In the second case:

```
Transpose[Join[u, v, w, 2]] == expected2
Transpose[ArrayFlatten[{{u, v, w}}]] == expected2
Flatten[{u, v, w}, {1, 3}] == expected2
```

Answer (score 8):

```
m=Flatten[{u, v, w}, {3, 1}]
m//MatrixForm
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use [ArrayFlatten](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ArrayFlatten.html):

```
ArrayFlatten[{{u,v,w}}]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
u = {{a}, {b}, {c}};
v = {{d}, {e}, {f}};
w = {{g}, {h}, {i}};
```

Using `ReplaceAll`

**case 1**

```
Transpose[{u, v, w}] /. {a_} :> a
```

> {{a, d, g}, {b, e, h}, {c, f, i}}

**case 2**

```
{u, v, w} /. {a_} :> a
```

> {{a, b, c}, {d, e, f}, {g, h, i}}

Answer (score 2):

```
u = {{a}, {b}, {c}};
v = {{d}, {e}, {f}};
w = {{g}, {h}, {i}};
```

**Case 1**

```
MapThread[Join, {u, v, w}]

(* {{a, d, g}, {b, e, h}, {c, f, i}} *)
```

Or

```
ArrayReduce[Splice, {u, v, w}, 1]

(* {{a, d, g}, {b, e, h}, {c, f, i}} *)
```

**Case 2**

```
MapThread[Join, Transpose@{u, v, w}]

(* {{a, b, c}, {d, e, f}, {g, h, i}} *)
```

Or

```
ArrayReduce[Splice, {u, v, w}, 2]

(* {{a, b, c}, {d, e, f}, {g, h, I}} *)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
u = {{a}, {b}, {c}};
v = {{d}, {e}, {f}};
w = {{g}, {h}, {i}};
```

---

Using `Replace` at level `2`

**case 1**

```
Replace[Thread@{u, v, w}, x_ :> Delete[x, 0], {2}]
```

> `{{a, d, g}, {b, e, h}, {c, f, i}}`

**case 2**

```
Replace[{u, v, w}, x_ :> Delete[x, 0], {2}]
```

> `{{a, b, c}, {d, e, f}, {g, h, i}}`

Answer (score 0):

Mathematica doesn't distinguish row and column vectors in the way many languages do, and so the construction {{a},{b},{c}} is awkward. You would be better off defining

```
u = {a, b, c};
v = {d, e, f};
w = {g, h, i};
```

Then you can achieve the two kinds of concatenation (as row vectors and as column vectors) straightforwardly:

```
{u, v, w}
```

and

```
Transpose[{u, v, w}]
```

which give the "Case 2" and "Case 1" matrices.